# Error occured during local report processing valid values are between '0' and '1'

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, ssrs-tablix

Trying to render an SSRS report that had a multi-select parameter option and multiple row groups within a single tablix. The report would fail inconsistently with the error message above. Entire error message was, "An error occured during local report processing. The value '3' is invalid. Valid values are between '0' and '1'. This error message is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the report was that there was a page break set to be between each instance of one of the 3 groups mentioned in the question. The tablix which contained the three groups also had the property "keep together on one page if possible" set to true. It seems that these two properties do not play nice together. Setting the keep together property to false allow the report to generate.

Link that led to answer, not officially marked as answer in this forum. Posting so its easier to find.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6693ff7-e407-4279-95c1-33184ebb9401/rrrenderingerror-after-upgrading-to-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices